# Debian-Installation without keyboard?

Tags: debian, installation, keyboard, debian-lenny

i have to install debian lenny right now, but i can't find my keyboard for the server (just use a laptop). Is there a way to install lenny without a keyboard?

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using [FAI - Debian's Fully Automatic Installation](http://fai-project.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Called a “headless” installation, have a look at these:

1. [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap), if you are installing a second image on a
   booting system:, or
2. [cdebootstrap](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cdebootstrap), if you can only
   boot from a CD.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can preseed the debian installation by letting the debian installer respond for
you to installation questions.
It could be a little tricky to get it work, but once you preseed file is ok,
no more need to have a keyboard to install a debian and no need to spend time... all
is automatic !
Have a look at :
http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.i386/apb.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is nicely documented tutorial how to install debian:

http://stratusandtheswirl.blogspot.com/2012/03/debian-testing-wheezy-keyboardless.html

Here is how you can do it for debian:
h
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OverSSH